# is there a way to turn windows 7 pc into a wifi hotspot with no software?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hotspot, virtual-wifi

i want to share my internet connection or a special wireless network between devices so this is my goal with no extra software.

i've been searching for so long but i still have not founded what i'm looking for. by the way i have 3 network adapters. a ethernet port  and two wifi antenas.

and yeah i tried with software but this is the ugly way for me, maybe you can come up with something very geeky for windows 7 or  8.

thank you very much!.

Comment: So are you asking how to turn a Windows 7 PC into a WiFi router?

Comment: What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: yeah win 7 pc as wifi hotspot, just sharing my connection with my home devices like phones or tablets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "with no third-party software", since obviously you'll need some software to configure the network. The answer is yes! In both cases, you will want to use the Internet Connection Sharing feature in Windows, which is possible by going to your Internet-connected network adaptor, Properties, Sharing tab, and enabling sharing. You then need to let other computers connect to your machine. There are two main ways:

1) Since you have multiple network cards, you can do this via Ad-Hoc WiFi if you want to. The main problem with this network mode is that some devices don't support it, although all computers should. *Note: these instructions are for Win8.1, but should be adaptable to Win7 easily.* Go to the "Network and Sharing Center" and click the option for "Set up a new connection or network". There should be an option like "Set up a peer-to-peer 'ad-hoc' network" or similar (it's missing on Win8.1). Select that, give the network a name and set its security, and then connect to it from other computers.

2) Starting with Win7, there's a built-in ability to act as a "real" WiFi hotspot - broadcast an "Infrastructure" node - even if you only have one network card (though it will usually work better when you have more than one). The instructions are here: http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3849841/How-to-Create-Wireless-Hosted-Networks-in-Windows-7.htm The general idea is that you use the `netsh` command-line tool (must be run as Admin) to configure the "hostednetwork" how you want it, then tell Windows to start it. Once it is started, other computers can connect to it, and through it, can connect to the Internet.